# Multidimensional vector classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm currently working in a project where I need to classify certain types of events. For each event I get readings from different sensors and the length for each type of event varies from around 300ms up to 1500ms. I need to build a classifier for this but I've never done something like this using multiple vectors at the same time. I have some experience using neural networks and K-Means clustering but only with single value features. What would be an starting point  to solve this kind of problem? I've been stuck with it for a while and i'm still not able to figure it out. If it is using python or C# that would be a plus.

Comment: what do you mean by "length of a type"? You'll need to get more specific on this, and if possible illustrate the vectors. Within each sensor's data, is the dimensionality consistent in cardinality? What are you trying to classify?

Comment: I meant that an event can last a certain period of time Ex: Event A last 700ms, Event B lasts 600ms, Event C lasts 500ms and so on. So the data is not cardinal consistent between different events. Im getting the values from the accelerometers of a car and i'm trying to classify certain kind of movements.

Answer (score 0):

Look at time series distance functions such as

Dynamic Time Warping

and appropriate feature extraction methods. For example, FFT, wavelets etc. *may* be appropriate, or not.

Comment: Thanks!, I began to read about this topic and it seems that it could help me with the task, I'll post if I have any good approach with it.